# What happens when a validator earns more than their staked 32 ETH?

Tags: proof-of-stake, eth-2.0

What happens when a validator earns back more than their staked 32 ETH? The "nothing at stake" situation kicks in then...no? And it becomes cheaper for a validator to misbehave.

Or will they be required to re-stake another 32 ETH to continue validating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A validator who has staked 32 ETH and earned another 32 ETH in rewards now has 64 ETH:

- 32 "staked" (i.e., earning rewards and at risk of penalties).
- 32 simply sitting there, waiting to be collected as rewards.

If the validator exits, they will receive 64 ETH (assuming no penalties or slashings).

I see no reason to say the validator has "nothing at stake" simply because they have earned another 32 ETH.

An absurdist analogy might be to ask *"If someone is staking $50k of ETH and then earns $50k mowing lawns, do they have nothing at stake?"*